# childBrowser plugin on phonegap build not working

Tags: cordova, phonegap-plugins, phonegap-build, childbrowser

I am building a phonegap + jquery mobile App,
I am trying to add a link that will open a web page in a child browser with the childbrowser phonegap plugin.

I see in the adobe phonegap build site that in order to add the childbrowser plugin I just need to add:

```
<gap:plugin name="com.phonegap.plugins.childbrowser" />
```

in the config.xml file

[See this link](https://build.phonegap.com/plugins/2)

I did That and it is not working
What am I missing here?

Thank you.

this is my code:

```
<!DOCTYPE HTML><html>
<head>
    <meta name = "viewport" content = "user-scalable=no,width=device-width" />
    <meta http-equiv="Content-type" content="text/html; charset=utf-8">
    <title>Test Page</title>
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="js/jquery.mobile-1.4.0/demos/css/themes/default/jquery.mobile-1.4.0.min.css">
    <script type="text/javascript" charset="utf-8" src="cordova.js"></script>
    <script src="js/jquery.mobile-1.4.0/demos/js/jquery.js"></script>
    <script src="js/jquery.mobile-1.4.0/demos/js/jquery.mobile-1.4.0.min.js"></script>
    <script type="text/javascript" charset="utf-8">
        function init(){
            document.addEventListener("deviceready", ready, true);
        }
        function ready() {
            console.log("phonegap is ready !");
        }
    </script></head> <body onload="init();">
<div data-role="page" id="home">
    <div data-role="content">

        <a href="#" onClick="window.plugins.childBrowser.showWebPage('http://www.google.com')">Open link in child browser !</a>

    </div>

</div>
```

and this is my config.xml file

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<widget xmlns = "http://www.w3.org/ns/widgets"
    xmlns:gap = "http://phonegap.com/ns/1.0"
    id        = "il.co.app.chazak"
    versionCode="1.0"
    version   = "1.0">
    <preference name="phonegap-version" value="3.1.0" />
    <name>chazak</name>
    <description>Chazak book librery</description>
    <author href="http://www.shtibel.com" email="dushy@shtibel.com">Dushy</author>
    <preference name="phonegap-version" value="2.9.0" />
    <preference name="orientation" value="default" />
    <preference name="target-device" value="universal" />
    <preference name="fullscreen" value="false" />
    <preference name="webviewbounce" value="true" />
    <preference name="prerendered-icon" value="true" />
    <preference name="stay-in-webview" value="true" />
    <preference name="ios-statusbarstyle" value="default" />
    <preference name="detect-data-types" value="true" />
    <preference name="exit-on-suspend" value="false" />
    <preference name="show-splash-screen-spinner" value="true" />
    <preference name="auto-hide-splash-screen" value="true" />
    <preference name="disable-cursor" value="true" />
    <preference name="android-minSdkVersion" value="7" />
    <preference name="android-maxSdkVersion" value="17" />
    <preference name="android-installLocation" value="auto" />
    <preference name="splash-screen-duration" value="0" />
    <preference name="load-url-timeout" value="0" />
    <feature name="http://api.phonegap.com/1.0/file"/>
    <feature name="http://api.phonegap.com/1.0/notification"/>
    <icon src="icon/iphone/Icon.png" gap:platform="ios" width="57" height="57" />
    <icon src="icon/iphone/Icon-72.png" gap:platform="ios" width="72" height="72" />
    <icon src="icon/iphone/Icon-2x.png" gap:platform="ios" width="114" height="114" />
    <icon src="icon/iphone/Icon-72-2x.png" gap:platform="ios" width="144" height="144" />
    <icon src="icon/android/ldpi.png" gap:platform="android" gap:density="ldpi" />
    <icon src="icon/android/mdpi.png" gap:platform="android" gap:density="mdpi" />
    <icon src="icon/android/hdpi.png" gap:platform="android" gap:density="hdpi" />
    <icon src="icon/android/xhdpi.png" gap:platform="android" gap:density="xhdpi" />
    <gap:splash src="splash/iphone/Default.png" width="320" height="480" />
    <gap:splash src="splash/iphone/Default-2x.png" width="640" height="960" />
    <gap:splash src="splash/iphone/Default-568h2x.png" width="640" height="1136" />
    <gap:splash src="splash/iphone/Default-Portrait.png" width="768" height="1024 " />
    <gap:splash src="splash/android/ldpi.png" gap:platform="android" gap:density="ldpi" />
    <gap:splash src="splash/android/mdpi.png" gap:platform="android" gap:density="mdpi" />
    <gap:splash src="splash/android/hdpi.png" gap:platform="android" gap:density="hdpi" />

    <gap:plugin name="com.phonegap.plugins.childbrowser" version="4.2.1" />

    <access origin="*" />
    <access uri="*" subdomains="true" />

</widget>
```

Comment: why don't you use inAppBrowser? it replaced childbrowser long time ago

Comment: Can you direct me to an example code?

Comment: Dose the inAppBrowser have an option to show the app header and footer and can it show PDF file?

Comment: I try the inAppBrowser but get this error on adobe phonegap build:  plugin unsupported: org.apache.cordova.inappbrowser

Comment: Now it works, but How can I show the App header / footer?

Comment: You can't, the inAppBrowser is full screen.

Comment: It can show PDF files on iOS, on android just if they are online and you use google docs url to open it, or if it's on the SD card and you open it with "_system" option, it will open the PDF on an istalled PDF reader if you have one.

Answer (score 1):

you have to include the `childbrowser.js` script after `cordova.js`:

```
<script type="text/javascript" charset="utf-8" src="childbrowser.js"></script>
```

[childbrowser plugin doc](https://github.com/phonegap-build/ChildBrowser/blob/9b580d92e8d74f316c5adbda2ece2f7641a5b4a2/README.md#childbrowser-javascript-api)

Comment: If I add the childbrowser.js then I get error on the phone gap build that childbrowser is not supported what can I do to fix it?

Comment: childbrowser only supports cordova versions 2.5.0, 2.7.0, 2.9.0. So u have to set Cordova version in config.xml to any of these versions and build: `<preference name="phonegap-version" value="2.9.0" />`